# How do I make Home / End keys behave Windows/Linux like in Terminal.app on Mac OS on Mac Pro laptop?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, keymap

I was wondering if somebody knows how to use home/end keys behave in a Windows/ Linux fashion.  What I mean is that when I press Apple + Left (Home combo on a mac book pro laptop) it should go to the beginning of the line, and Apple + Right to the end of the line. Right now they change focus to the top of the scroll history. Drives me crazy.

Home / End keys behave as expected in TextMate and such but not in terminal, which makes me think it's that app specific. I found some page saying that I need to remap key bindings but I can't do that on every mac i touch. So is there another shorcut in Mac I can use or how do I make Home/End keys behave as expected?

Thank you

Comment: Linux does that with home/end keys? I only knew about ctrl-a for beginning of line and ctrl-e for end of line. I thought home/end keys were used only by Windows and OS/2 for that.

Comment: Well at least Debian. You spooked me so I just confirmed using Debian Lenny and Putty on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three levels of key mappings in this case:

1. Terminal.app
2. The shell, which is probably **bash**
3. For **bash**, the editor mode, which is probably **emacs**

For **emacs**, `Ctrl-A` goes to the beginning of the line and `Ctrl-E` goes to the end of the line. [Here are some other key combos](https://superuser.com/questions/120333/), including for the alternative **vi** mode.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Terminal maps <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd> to “go to start/end of line”, and if the program you’re using is showing the Alternate Screen (most full-screen applications like `vim`, `emacs`, `top`, etc. do this) then <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> are mapped to start/end of line without requiring the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier.